# Can someone explain how SystemJS works?

Tags: systemjs

I just want to know how SystemJS works.  My idea is that it executes modules transpiled for it, but I really don't know how it gets a System.import-ed module executed.

For instance, I have my Angular2 app transpiled with Gulp and Typescript to a bundle and load it via SystemJS. The app is loaded perfectly: I get no console errors in my browser, but the application doesn't start.

Do I need special prerequisites for transpiling and running Typescript code?